# How do I Remove a Google Contact from Phone without Deleting it from Google Account?

Tags: contacts, google-account, google-contacts

My work Google account is one of many synced to my phone. I'm a teacher so I have lot's of student emails as contacts on my work Google account.  When I do a search for say "David" on my phone's contact list all my students I've ever had with the name David show up and it is very cluttered.

**Is there a way to remove the contacts of my work Google account from my phone without deleting them from the associated Google account, and while still keeping access to emails from that account on my phone?**

Comment: It may be easier to find a contact manager app that allows to limit search to a certain group or account instead of trying to delete an contact entry that does not sync into the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If Your Phone is Set to Display Contacts from Google Account, it will likely keep showing except if you deselect the linked google account from displaying its contacts. Else, you will need to delet the contact and syncronize it.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping that wasn't the case.

Comment: I just figured out that in my phone's "Contacts" preferences I can set a google account to not display any contacts which is exactly what I wanted.  I think that's what you are referring to, but I didn't get it when I read your response.  Some more details would make this a better response.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with having my husband's Google account on my phone. It synced his contacts to my phone.

What I did was this:
Turned Airplane mode on.
Settings>Accounts-Google>[your account], and make sure Contacts sync is turned off. Make sure you turn off sync on all the Google accounts. Next, go to Settings>Apps, tap Menu>Show System, and select Contact Storage. Clear Cache/Data.

What I did also was select Calls, Call Settings, Contacts, and Contact Migrator; Clear Cache/Data.

Restarted the phone, turned Airplane mode off, turned sync on just my accounts on and opened contacts. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I the same problem with my work google contacts. I tried the answers above but they did not work for me.

Here is what I did instead. (Note: I have a Redmi Note 10.)

1. Use a computer to delete all your google contacts. You can probably do this with your phone too. The phone will then sync and remove the contacts.
2. After the contacts are removed, go to Settings>Accounts & sync>Google> Select the google account and disable the syncing of contacts.
3. Go to Google Contacts and recover your contacts from the trash. These contacts will no longer appear on your phone's contacts.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).